# SQL : How to reuse count(*) computed value?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 9.4.

I have a select statement in my query that looks like this :

```
SELECT date_part('year'::text, c.date) AS yyyy,
    to_char(c.date, 'MM'::text) AS monthnumber,
    to_char(c.date, 'TMMonth'::text) AS monthname,
    l.id AS lineID,
    n.id AS networkID,
    l.name AS lineName,
    count(c.*) AS count,
    count(distinct(c.date)) AS number_of_journeys,
```

I would like to reuse the two last columns (the computed ones) to compute another column like this :

```
SELECT date_part('year'::text, c.date) AS yyyy,
    to_char(c.date, 'MM'::text) AS monthnumber,
    to_char(c.date, 'TMMonth'::text) AS monthname,
    l.id AS lineID,
    n.id AS networkID,
    l.name AS lineName,
    count(c.*) AS count,
    count(distinct(c.date)) AS number_of_journeys,
    count / number_of_journeys AS frequentation_moyenne
```

Is it possible to do so ?

Thank you

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: Most RDBMSs won't allow you to refer to a column alias within the same query.  But you can just give it a shot if you want.  By the way, don't use `count` (or any other reserved words) as an alias.  I doubt that  a query with  `count(c.*) as count` will even execute successfully.

Comment: I'm using postgres, edited the question

Comment: Thanks for the naming tip, that's dumb of me for sure to name this column count.

Comment: Closely related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89746/use-result-of-aggregate-in-same-select

Comment: @erwin-brandstetter That's exactly my question - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in SQL Server, you would have to use one of these:

```
SELECT date_part('year'::text, c.date) AS yyyy,
to_char(c.date, 'MM'::text) AS monthnumber,
to_char(c.date, 'TMMonth'::text) AS monthname,
l.id AS lineID,
n.id AS networkID,
l.name AS lineName,
count(c.*) AS count,
count(distinct(c.date)) AS number_of_journeys,
count(c.*) / count(distinct(c.date)) AS frequentation_moyenne
```

OR

```
Select yyyy, monthnumber, monthname, lineID, networkID, lineName, count, number_of_journery, count / number_of_journeys AS frequentation_moyenne
from
(SELECT date_part('year'::text, c.date) AS yyyy,
to_char(c.date, 'MM'::text) AS monthnumber,
to_char(c.date, 'TMMonth'::text) AS monthname,
l.id AS lineID,
n.id AS networkID,
l.name AS lineName,
count(c.*) AS count,
count(distinct(c.date)) AS number_of_journeys)
```

Comment: First method is what I was already doing.
Second method is what I was looking for I guess, however when benchmarking it against the first method, they both consume the same amount of time. Maybe my dataset is too small to see the difference. Thanks anyway !